# Override default behavior of def destroy() in ModelViewSet to allow query parameters

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I understand the intended `DELETE` behavior in DRF `ModelViewSet` is that a `pk` must be specified. For example, `DELETE /api/document/1/`.

However, I'm trying to implement `DELETE` using query parameters which I understand should be acceptable in a REST API. For example, `DELETE /api/document/?product_id=1`, which would `DELETE` all documents associated with a `product_id`.

When you pass query parameters to Django with `DELETE`, it returns:

```
{
    "detail": "Method \"DELETE\" not allowed."
}
```

Remove the parameters and specify a `pk` and it works fine.

If that is the case, if you are wanting to delete all documents related to a `product_id`, you'd first need to query to get the list of `documents` related to that `product_id`, iterate through it and `DELETE` on each `pk`.

Seems like there should be a better way.

I'm testing if I can even override the `destroy()`, grab the query parameters, and do what I need to do:

```
class DocumentToProductViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = DocumentToProduct.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DocumentToProductSerializer

    def destroy(self, request):
        print('destroy test')
        pass
```

The request doesn't reach the method before I get that error since `'destroy test'` doesn't print out in the console.

I'm using `SimpleRouter()` which is likely where the error is generated from, and have also have tried the following but I'm not wanting to add another end point like `/api/documents/delete/?product_id=1`:

```
@action(method=['delete'], detail=False)
def delete(self, request):
    ...
```

Just simply wanting to do a: `DELETE /api/documents/?product_id=1`.

Is there anyway to do this in Django / DRF, to allow query parameters to get through routers on `DELETE`?

Comment: Can you explain why do you want to pass query params? Do you want to do bulk destroy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, the problem here is that you are using a built-in router. That is just the way [SimpleRouter](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#simplerouter) builds the URL, it expects a `lookup` parameter on destroy action (or delete requests, as you wish):

```py
...
Route(
    url=r'^{prefix}/{lookup}{trailing_slash}$',
    mapping={
        'get': 'retrieve',
        'put': 'update',
        'patch': 'partial_update',
        'delete': 'destroy'
    },
    name='{basename}-detail',
    detail=True,
    initkwargs={'suffix': 'Instance'}
),
...
```

What you can do, for instance, is move this `'delete': 'destroy'` mapping to another URL with a [custom router](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#custom-routers). In this case you want to send a `DELETE` request to `api/documents/` which is also your `list` endpoint, so:

```py
from rest_framework.routers import Route, DynamicRoute, SimpleRouter

class CustomRouter(SimpleRouter):
    routes = [
        Route(
            url=r'^{prefix}/$',
            mapping={'get': 'list', 'delete': 'destroy'},
            name='{basename}-list',
            detail=False,
            initkwargs={'suffix': 'List'}
        ),
        Route(
            url=r'^{prefix}/{lookup}/$',
            mapping={'get': 'retrieve'},
            name='{basename}-detail',
            detail=True,
            initkwargs={'suffix': 'Detail'}
        )
    ]

custom_router = CustomRouter()
custom_router.register(r'documents', DocumentToProductViewSet)
```

And then, handle the `destroy` action:

```py
class DocumentToProductViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = DocumentToProduct.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DocumentToProductSerializer

    def destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        product_id = request.GET.get('product_id', None)
        if product_id:
            try:
                product = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
                product.documents.all().delete()

            except DocumentToProduct.DoesNotExist:
                return Response({'message': 'object not found'})
        else:
            return Response({'message': 'query string parameter not found'})

        return Response({'message': 'object documents successfully deleted.'})
```